# Where do these numbers come from?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to learn Java by myself and I have encountered a problem that I don't quite understand.
I tried to write a program to calculate the cross sum.  My idea was to split the entered number into a `char` array and then simply 
run through the array and calculate the sum.

This is what I have:

```
public static int calcCrossSum (long number){
    int sum = 0;
    char[] charArray = String.valueOf(number).toCharArray();

    for( int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++){
        sum += charArray[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If I try this method with the number 123, I get 150
 as a result and I don't know why. I've tried to use the debugger and it seems that my variable `test` adds strange numbers to itself even though the debugger shows that the content of the Array seems to be correct.

I'd be grateful if someone could explain to me what I did wrong and where those numbers come from. If there's anything unclear I'll happily try to add further information.

Comment: You are adding the character values instead of their integer values. Parse them into an integer value before adding to `sum`. Google "converting character to integer in Java"

Comment: Ok i got the problem but where do these numbers come from? Am I adding the the ASCII value of the character ?

Answer (score 2):

Chars have a integer value associated with them.  You should do like this:

```
public static int calcCrossSum (long number){
    int sum = 0;
    char[] charArray = String.valueOf(number).toCharArray();

    for( int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++){
        sum += Integer.parseInt(("" + charArray[i]));
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making a sum with the unicode value of each char.
The values are '1' = 49, '2' = 50, '3' = 51.

If you want to make a sum with the unicode values and get the real values of each char you can make a function like this:

```
public static int charToInt(char c){
    return (int) c - 48; //48 is the value of '0'
}
```

and call the function:

```
public static int calcCrossSum (long number){
    int sum = 0;
    char[] charArray = String.valueOf(number).toCharArray();

    for( int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++){
        sum += charToInt(charArray[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You can look for the unicode value of each value [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF)

Comment: Java (.NET, JavaScript, HTML, …) use Unicode, not ASCII. So, an ASCII table would not give all of the values. Here is a [Unicode table](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are adding character but you have to add integer .Because  `+` operand on `char` will always give you the sum  of its unicodes values.

Instead to find the sum of digit you can do

```
public static int calcCrossSum (long number){
    int sum = 0;
    while ( number > 0 )
        {
            sum += number % 10; 
            number /= 10; 

        } 
    return sum;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/mvTM0X)

Answer (score 0):

That's my solution, i'm sure you could make it more simple, but there you go:

```
public static int cross_sums(int input) {
    int output = 0;
    do {
        output += input % 10;
        input /= 10;
    } while (input > 0);

    if (output > 9) {
        output = cross_sums(output);
    }
    return output;
}
```